# What is the easiest way to replace a cellphone with a mini laptop

Tags: security, android, 4g

Given the [security concerns](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2011/sep/19/android-free-software-stallman) that seem to surround modern cellphones in general and Android phones in particular, Ḯ'm considering to move away from using a cellphone and replacing its most important functionality with Free Software products that would run on a mini laptop. I wonder if other people have already been doing this and if there exists guides for doing this easily. My current plan is to get a laptop with an integrated 4G router or with a separate laptop and a 4G hotspot. There obviously exists quite a lot of functionality in a smart phone whereby I believe that compromises need to be made in other fronts too apart from the obvious compactness issue which I will simply have to tolerate for now.

Comment: This seems like a discussion and opinion topic, unrelated to Ubuntu support. If you are *just discovering* security concerns about mobile devices, you're about a decade behind.

Comment: Not sure what "mini laptop" is, but you can buy tablets that accept SIM cards and their "footprint" is about 8" to 12" on average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [gpd pocket 2](https://www.gpd.hk/gpdpocket2) may be worth looking at. Here's a [video review](https://ubuntu-mate.org/gpd-pocket/) (with windows though) and here's a [linux compatibility](https://liliputing.com/2018/08/linux-on-the-gpd-pocket-2-ubuntu-debian-and-fedora.html) overview. There's also [this](https://ubuntu-mate.org/gpd-pocket/) optimized ubuntu mate version.